# changing where pam_mkhomedir makes a directory

Tags: pam, nfs4, 389-ds

I want to create user directories for an LDAP user (389-ds) If they don't exist so I am using pam_mkhomedir . How do I create these directories on a different mount point say /nfs/home instead . I know there is a previous Question on this But I don't understand his/her solution. Any Help is appreciated. I am new to administration

Comment: If there is already a question for this, then please tell us what you did and didn't understand about the other solution and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create the homedir at whatever location is listed as the users homedir, there is no "default". Everything else doesn't make any sense.

If you want Alice's home directory to be `/nfs/home/alice`, put it into the LDAP record.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I deleted the test user and created it again for some reason  it worked well the second time round